# PyMC3 fails to execute on MacOS Big Sur/ PyCharm

Tags: theano, pymc3

I am attempting to run some simple PyMC3 code in PyCharm on MacOS Big Sur but the execution fails and throws the following error:

```
Exception: ('Compilation failed (return status=1): ld: library not found for -lSystem. clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). ', '[Elemwise{add,no_inplace}(TensorConstant{1.0}, TensorConstant{1.0})]')
```

I am using PyCharm 2020.3.2. I am able to install pymc3 (version 3.8) and theano (1.0.4) into the environment. Code I am attempting to run follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymc3 as pm

np.random.seed(123)
n_experiments = 4
theta_real = 0.35
data = stats.bernoulli.rvs(p=theta_real, size=n_experiments)

with pm.Model() as our_first_model:
    theta = pm.Beta('theta', alpha=1, beta=1)
    y = pm.Bernoulli('y', p=theta, observed=data)
    start = pm.find_MAP()
    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(1000, step=step, start=start)
    burnin = 100
    chain = trace[burnin:]
    pm.traceplot(chain, lines={'theta':theta_real});
```

I disabled Apple System Integrity Protection on some speculation that maybe Apple hiding /usr/include might be the source of the problem; it made no difference. No clue how else to fix this.

Comment: Do you have `clang` installed?

Comment: Yes, Apple clang version 12.0.0

Comment: Can you post the output of `clang -v` and `find / -name clang`?

Comment: clang -v output: `clang version 10.0.0 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/<my name redacted>/anaconda3/envs/BayesianMC3/bin`

Comment: find / -name clang: `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/clang
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/swift/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang` there are more but out of character space here

Comment: Well, seems like your anaconda is broken. Update anaconda and try again. If that doesn't work try to install pymc3 in the system python not the Anaconda one. This will use the system clang and not the anaconda clang.

Comment: Thanks, you are right it seems my anaconda is broken, I updated it but it didn't seem to help, so instead installed pymc3 in the system python and ran from there, and it worked. Of course, now I have a different problem, but one I vaguely remember from before Big Sur, it's throwing errors on multiprocessing, now I just have to remember how I fixed it haha. Anyway, I very much appreciate the help!

Comment: Ok moving this to a "kind of answer" for posterity. I also sometimes have problems with multiprocessing on Linux, but only for some models. If you do not manage to find a solution for the multiprocessing issue create a new question and I might be able to help you with this if your symptoms are similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

From the information in comments it seems like your anaconda is broken.
Update anaconda and try again.

If that doesn't work, try to install PyMC3 in the system Python not the Anaconda one.
This will use the system `clang` and not the Anaconda `clang`.